# How to plot green and red arrows over a plotly CandleStick graph?

Tags: python, python-2.7, plotly

I have tried to plot the Candle Sticks for my data using the `plotly` library with Python. Using the typical plotting way, I got the following graph:

```
Candle = go.Candlestick(x=stock.index,
                       open=stock.open,
                       high=stock.high,
                       low=stock.low,
                       close=stock.close
                       )
```

Output:
[image: candles image]

I was expecting to draw the image is something like the following:
[image: candles with arrow]

See the up green arrow and the down red arrow. I want to know how to plot that.

Comment: I don't know the reason of the downvotes but maybe you can produce a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 5):

I don't know which one is the logic for selecting arrows but you can play from here. First download data from [Yahoo-finance TESLA](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TSLA/history?p=TSLA) and then

```
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
stock =  pd.read_csv("~/Downloads/TSLA.csv")

d=3
stock["Marker"] = np.where(stock["Open"]<stock["Close"], stock["High"]+d, stock["Low"]-d)
stock["Symbol"] = np.where(stock["Open"]<stock["Close"], "triangle-up", "triangle-down")
stock["Color"] = np.where(stock["Open"]<stock["Close"], "green", "red")

Candle = go.Candlestick(x=stock.Date,
                       open=stock.Open,
                       high=stock.High,
                       low=stock.Low,
                       close=stock.Close
                       )

Trace = go.Scatter(x=stock.Date,
                   y=stock.Marker,
                   mode='markers',
                   name ='markers',
                   marker=go.Marker(size=20,
                                    symbol=stock["Symbol"],
                                    color=stock["Color"])
                   )
py.plot([Candle, Trace])
```

Comment: Good attempt.. but it is not like the one I am expecting still good.. Than you. If you can edit it to get the output I expect then please let me know...

Comment: @JafferWilson I explicitly said that this was an idea to solve your problem not the solution. If you don't write what's the logic for showing or not arrows I can't do that much. Then wherever you have the logic you just set the other elements in `stock["Marker"]` as `np.nan` and that's it.